# Ruby add dynamics (loop) into Regexp.union . Simple string replication doesn't work

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to add logic into my `Regexp.union` command so I can build it from array where number of elements could be different. In my example case#1 works OK, then I tried to replicate this string and its failed, looks like `Regexp.union` does little more inside then I know, `regU` and `RegU2` in my sample matched only as `to_s`. I figured out that type is `Regexp` but can't find how to convert it, if it doable at all . Is it possible to accomplish. I also started case#3 to work with native `union` in the loop but stumbled also.  Tx ruby gurus !!

```
RegexData = ['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie']
line = ' the alpha alphaaaa  asdfdsaf bravo'

###1 Regex.Join with fix number of elements Works OK
regU = Regexp.union(/#{RegexData[0].chomp}/ix, /#{RegexData[1].chomp}/ix, /#{RegexData[2].chomp}/ix )
pos1 = line.enum_for(:scan, regU).map { Regexp.last_match.begin(0) } 
puts '...1  regU: ' +  regU.to_s.length.to_s + '  ' +  regU.to_s     
puts 'scan1: ' + pos1.to_s      
p regU.instance_of? String  ## not string
p regU.instance_of? Array   ## not Array   
p regU.instance_of? Class    ## still not
p regU.class      ## Regexp  !!!!!!
puts 



###2 loop with fixing regex format,  no results , even regex match as string!!!!!!!!!!
regU2 = '(?-mix:'
RegexData.each_with_index {|val, index|     
    if val == RegexData.last then valx = '(?ix-m:' + val.chomp + '))'    else    valx = '(?ix-m:' + val.chomp + ')|'  end
    regU2 << valx
    }
puts '...2  regU2: ' +  regU2.to_s.length.to_s + '  ' +  regU2.to_s 
pos2 = line.enum_for(:scan, regU2).map { Regexp.last_match.begin(0) } 
puts 'scan2: ' + pos2.to_s   


if regU.to_s == regU2.to_s  then puts  'Bingo to_s matched!!!! ' else puts 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' end    
if regU      == regU2       then puts  'Bingo      matched!!!! ' else puts 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' end
```

Comment: An regex has class [`Regexp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html) (`//.class #=> Regexp`). You can convert a string to a regex by embedding it `/#{'your string'}/` or by passing it to the constructor [`Regexp.new('your string')`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#method-c-new). Keep in mind that the output will not escape regex chars. If you want escaped chars call [`Regexp.escape('your string')`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#method-c-escape) and feed the output to one of the above methods.

Comment: Tx Johan !!!!,  Success story with `Regex.new(regU2)`  Not sure why I can't put any stars/points to your answer. Best M

Comment: I extended my comment somewhat and added it as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52064186/3982562).

Answer (score 1):

[`Regexp::Union`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#method-c-union) unions your patters. If strings are provided they are escaped by the method. If you provide regexes the options are preserved and no characters are escaped:

```
regex_data = ['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie', '1 + 1 = 2']
Regexp.union(regex_data)
#=> /alpha|bravo|charlie|1\ \+\ 1\ =\ 2/
```

To prevent regex char escaping or if you want to add in some options you'll have to convert the strings into regexes first. This can be done by using [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-map), providing the string to the `Regexp` constructor and optionally some regex options. Using [`Regexp::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#method-c-new) method doesn't escape characters by default:

```
regexes = regex_data.map { |str| Regexp.new(str) }
Regexp.union(regexes)
#=> /(?-mix:alpha)|(?-mix:bravo)|(?-mix:charlie)|(?-mix:1 + 1 = 2)/

options = Regexp::EXTENDED | Regexp::IGNORECASE # See Regexp::new reference above
regexes = regex_data.map { |str| Regexp.new(str, options) }
Regexp.union(regexes)
#=> /(?ix-m:alpha)|(?ix-m:bravo)|(?ix-m:charlie)|(?ix-m:1 + 1 = 2)/
```

If you want the string with escaped regex chars you'll have to pass it through [`Regexp::escape`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#method-c-escape) first and pass the result to the constructor.

```
regexes = regex_data.map { |str| Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(str), options) }
Regexp.union(regexes)
#=> /(?ix-m:alpha)|(?ix-m:bravo)|(?ix-m:charlie)|(?ix-m:1\ \+\ 1\ =\ 2)/
```

---

If all values have to be [`chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-chomp)ed considerer doing that first so you don't have to mix string logic with regex logic:

```
regex_data = regex_data.map(&:chomp)
# also written as: regex_data = regex_data.map { |str| str.chomp }
# or if you don't mind mutating your variable
regex_data.map!(&:chomp)
```